# How would I go about testing if there is any significant difference in the mean battery life between an Android phone and an iPhone?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Let's say that the following is the data for battery life in minutes for an Android phone:

```
Android<-c(60,64,62,71,78,64,82,77,71,72,68,66,65,80,79,71,63,60,61)
```

And let's say that the following is the data for battery life in minutes for an iPhone:

```
iPhone<-(71,78,64,77,72,61,66,71,73,90,62,63,66,67,72,68,70,68,81)
```

Would I simply do `var.test(Android,iPhone)` and then see if variance are equal, and if they are, proceed to a pooled `t-test` where `var.equal=TRUE`? What if the variances aren't equal?

Comment: Taking statistical part aside, for this to be a fair comparison, you would need either to make sure that the conditions are comparable (same kind of activity, same apps running etc) or you have a large, random sample.

Answer (score 0):

Besides looking at the plots, you could use the Levene-Test to check whether variances are equal:

```
install.packages("car")
library (car)

leveneTest(Android,iPhone)
```

If the test does indeed reveal heteroscedasticity (*p* < .05 or the significance level of choice for your dicipline), a follow-up question to ask would be whether the violation is so grave that you actually have to do something about it. If that's the case, you can transform your data to induce homoscedasticity, eg. employing Box-Cox transformation.

Answer (score 0):

A two-sample Welch t test, which does not require equal population variances,
seems appropriate.

Importing your data into R, and looking at basic descriptive statistics, we have:

```
x = Android<-c(60,64,62,71,78,64,82,77,71,72,68,66,65,80,79,71,63,60,61)
y = iPhone<-c(71,78,64,77,72,61,66,71,73,90,62,63,66,67,72,68,70,68,81)

summary(x); length(x); sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  60.00   63.50   68.00   69.16   74.50   82.00 
[1] 19          # sample size
[1] 7.236199    # sample standard deviaation
summary(y); length(y); sd(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  61.00   66.00   70.00   70.53   72.50   90.00 
[1] 19
[1] 7.175331
```

Sample means are $\bar X = 69.16, \bar Y = 70.51,$ which do differ,
but not by much compared with the standard deviations, both near $7.$
The question is whether the difference in sample means is large enough
to be declared statistically significant at the 5% level, so that we
could say the population means $\mu_x, \mu_y$ are different.
That is, we want to test the null hypothesis $H_0: \mu_x=\mu_y$ against
the alternative $H_a: \mu_x \ne \mu_y.$

Boxplots do not show marked differences in location, but do show roughly
symmetrical samples. (Sample `x` at left.)

```
boxplot(x, y, col=c("skyblue2","wheat")
```

[image]

In order to use a t test, we should see if the data come from normal or nearly
normal populations. Shapiro-Wilk tests of normality have P-values above
$0.05 = 5\%,$ so do not reject the null hypothesis of normality.

```
shapiro.test(x)$p.val
[1] 0.1078691
shapiro.test(y)$p.val
[1] 0.1304247
```

Also, normal probability plots of the two samples show roughly linear patterns (some skewness in sample `y` at right),
so data seem close enough to normality to use a t test with sample sizes as
small as $n_1=n_2 = 19.$

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 qqnorm(x, col="blue"); qqline(x, lwd=2)
 qqnorm(y, col="brown"); qqline(y, lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Finally, a Welch two-sample t test shows a P-value above 5%, so the null
hypothesis cannot be rejected at the 5% level. We conclude that the
small difference in the sample means is not statistically significant.

```
t.test(x,y)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = -0.58533, df = 35.997, p-value = 0.562
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -6.109873  3.373031
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 69.15789  70.52632
```

*Notes:*

(1) Please see the comment by @Tim about the importance of having
random samples of battery lives under similar conditions. Any formal
statistical test is only as good as the data used for the test.

(2) There is no reason to assume that variabilities in battery lives
would be the same for the two types of phones. In fact, the sample variances are not much different. However, it is good statistical practice to use the Welch t test (instead of the pooled t test) unless you have strong prior information that population variances are nearly equal.

If there were marked differences in sample standard deviations, then the degrees of freedom in the Welch test would be reduced to allow for that. [The pooled t test would have had DF = 19 + 19 - 2 = 36; the reduction in the DF for the Welch test is very small for your data. (When sample sizes are equal, as here, the Welch and pooled t statistics are equal.)]